# PowerPoint-like resizable picture and text boxes as .NET controls

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I'm looking for a way to implement a surface (in C#, Windows Forms) where the user can add pictures and text in resizable boxes (with resize handles) - like in PowerPoint. Does anyone know a ready-made control (preferably free) that can do that?

This is what I mean:

[Text box http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4d88f329f2.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4d88f329f2.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a C# implementation of a Rect Tracker

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CSharpRectTracker.aspx